# How to use mixed case labels on buttons

Tags: material-design-lite

Is there a way to make the labels on buttons mixed case?  I have never seen anything but uppper case on the MDL demo components page.

```
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised">
  Mixed Case Here
</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is `text-transform: uppercase;` in class `.mdl-button`.

One possible solution may be to add a new class `my-mixed_case` to your button

```
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised my-mixed_case">
   Mixed Case Here
</button>
```

and define it (to reset the text transform):

```
.my-mixed_case.mdl-button {
   text-transform: none;
}
```

Comment: Awesome.  Good fix.